# Entity listener not called

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have the following entity and associated listener

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(InjuryListener::class)
class Injury(val description: String,
             @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) val id: Long = 0)

@Singleton
class InjuryListener : PreDeleteEventListener {
    @PreRemove
    fun preRemove(injury: Injury) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onPreDelete(event: PreDeleteEvent?): Boolean {
        val injury = event?.entity as Injury
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Yet when I delete an Injury neither of the the methods on my InjuryListener is called. Any clue about why that is?

Comment: How you are removing your entity ?

Comment: Through my repository defined as "@Repository interface InjuryRepository : CrudRepository<Injury, Long>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ilya Dyoshin wrote `@EntityListener` and `@PreRemove` are not used in Micronaut Data. But you can solve it by AOP technique.

At first create your own interceptor with a pre-delete logic that you need:

```
@Singleton
class InjuryPreDeleteInterceptor : MethodInterceptor<Injury, Boolean> {
    override fun intercept(context: MethodInvocationContext<Injury, Boolean>): Boolean {
        val injury = context.parameterValues[0] as Injury
        if (injury.someFlag) {
            // do not delete
        } else {
            // delete
            context.proceed()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Then create annotation that will trigger the `InjuryPreDeleteInterceptor`:

```
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Around
@Type(InjuryPreDeleteInterceptor::class)
annotation class VisitInjuryDelete
```

And add `delete()` method signature annotated by previously created `@VisitInjuryDelete` annotation into the `InjuryRepository` interface:

```
@VisitInjuryDelete
override fun delete(Injury entity)
```

You can find more info about AOP in Micronaut here: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/aop.html

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are in micronaut world, majority of the "magic" is done during the compile-time. And one main statement of micronaut-data is that no runtime metamodel exist.

This effectively means, that there is no `EntityListener` annotation on your entity.

In micronaut world you should use `DataInterceptor` for implementing needed functionality.

Comment: Do you have an example or possible a link to one? I can't find much on Google